# Cannot execute tests in AppCenter, using calabash framework with React Native project

Tags: react-native-ios, calabash, visual-studio-app-center, xamarin-test-cloud

I am trying to execute **appcenter test prepare calabash --artifacts-dir "myArtifactsDir" --app-path "myAppPath" --project-dir "myProjectDir"** command via Terminal, and I am getting the following error:

Cannot prepare Calabash artifacts. Returning exit code 127; | Preparing tests... /bin/sh: test-cloud: command not found.

Not sure what am I missing? Some help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I was missing **xamarin-test-cloud** agent withing my project.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by agent, but you need xamarin-test-cloud gem (Ruby)